# How to use react-ga with HashRouter?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-router

I have been trying to integrate Google Analytics with my React App which uses HashRouter from react-router-dom v4. But it simply doesn't work complaining:

> Warning: < HashRouter> ignores the history prop. To use a custom
>   history, use `import { Router }` instead of `import { HashRouter as
>   Router }`.

The same question has been posted on Github here: [HashRouter not responding to History](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/1913) but no solutions provided yet.

**I have to stick with HashRouter for the project without using any HOC.** Is this possible?

My current implementation:

```
ReactGA.initialize('UA-XXXXXXXX-X');
const history = createHistory()
history.listen((location, action) => {
  ReactGA.set({ page: location.pathname });
  ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname);
});

ReactDOM.render((
    <HashRouter history={history}>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" name="App" component={App} />
        </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
),document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: No, back then i couldn't find a solution to this. Just initialized google analytics directly from the static page for tracking visits and used a in-web app messaging platform for tracking page views data. Just a hack but worked

Comment: I solved it. I used the same implementation as done in the demo app of ReactGA. But you will have to use the withTracker HOC provided there.

Comment: In case you are willing, can you please add those lines of code as an answer to this question so that I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Good thinking, added it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code provided in the demo project also uses HashRouter. 
As seen here;
https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/blob/master/demo/app/Router.jsx

Use of HOC ,withTracker, is not a must. It is only made to insert tracking trigger on each page easily. You can achieve same result, if you implement same code in your own page components.

Then you would need to add below code to each component you want to track manually;

```
  const trackPage = (page) => {
    ReactGA.set({
      page
    });
    ReactGA.pageview(page);
  };

    componentDidMount() {
      const page = this.props.location.pathname;
      trackPage(page);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      const currentPage = this.props.location.pathname;
      const nextPage = nextProps.location.pathname;

      if (currentPage !== nextPage) {
        trackPage(nextPage);
      }
    }
```